# Get all combinations of sub phrases from a string

Tags: vb.net, string, combinations

To do some sort of "fuzzy" matching I need to extract all variations of sub phrases from a string that a user can input.

The few examples I've tried don't seem to do the whole job - they seem to loop through and grab sub phrases only that are side by side but not distributed throughout - e.g. :

Original input - "heavy duty cable reel" - gives when getting 2 word sub phrases :

heavy duty

duty cable

cable reel

But I also want :

heavy cable

heavy reel

duty reel

So in effect "missing out" words when building the sub phrases. Ideally I need to return 3 & 2 word sub phrases for a 4 word original input, and 4, 3 & 2 for 5 word input and so on.

```
For i As Integer = lst.Count To 1 Step -1 
    For j As Integer = 1 To i 
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder 
        sb.Append("( ") 
        For k As Integer = 0 To (lst.Count - i) 
            sb.Append(lst(j + k - 1) & ":" & j & ":" & k & ":" & i & " ") 
            Next 
        sb.Append(")") 
        rlst.Add(sb.ToString()) 
    Next 
Next
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried?

Comment: um shouldn't be too complicated if you stick these words in an array and then arrange the words in every pattern possible 1,2,3 - 2,3,1 etcetera

Comment: I don't need all terms in different orders - order isn't actually important. In your example I'd need 1,2,3 : 1,2 : 2,3 : 1,3.

Comment: I have tried the following (how do I post code?!) :

`For i As Integer = lst.Count To 1 Step -1
            For j As Integer = 1 To i
                Dim sb As New StringBuilder
                sb.Append("( ")

                For k As Integer = 0 To (lst.Count - i)
                    sb.Append(lst(j + k - 1) & ":" & j & ":" & k & ":" & i & " ")
                Next
                sb.Append(")")
                rlst.Add(sb.ToString())
            Next
        Next`

Comment: Add your code to your post by editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two nested for loops will do it for combinations of two words

```
Dim s = "heavy duty cable reel".Split()

For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 2
    For k As Integer = i + 1 To s.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(s(i) + " " + s(k))
    Next
Next
```

The output is

```
heavy duty
heavy cable
heavy reel
duty cable
duty reel
cable reel
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a version that gets all the phrase lengths from 2 to number of words - 1. I created a class for this.

```
Public Class PhraseBuilder
    Private words As String()
    Private phrases As List(Of String)

    Public Function GetList(ByVal initialPhrase As String) As List(Of String)
        words = initialPhrase.Split()
        phrases = New List(Of String)()
        For phraseLength As Integer = 2 To words.Length - 1
            AddPhrases("", 0, phraseLength)
        Next
        Return phrases
    End Function

    Private Sub AddPhrases(ByVal phrase As String, ByVal start As Integer,
                           ByVal wordCount As Integer)
        If wordCount >= 1 Then
            For i As Integer = start To words.Length - wordCount
                AddPhrases(phrase + " " + words(i), i + 1, wordCount - 1)
            Next i
        Else
            phrases.Add(phrase.TrimStart())
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can test it with

```
Sub PrintPhrases()
    Dim phraseBuilder = New PhraseBuilder()
    Dim phrases = phraseBuilder.GetList("heavy duty cable reel")
    For Each phrase As String In phrases
        Console.WriteLine(phrase)
    Next
End Sub
```

The result will be

```
heavy duty
heavy cable
heavy reel
duty cable
duty reel
cable reel
heavy duty cable
heavy duty reel
heavy cable reel
duty cable reel
```

---

Note that I used a recursion here. The recursion allows nesting the for-statements to an arbitrary depth. I did not use a `StringBuilder`, since we have to create copies of phrase beginnings. This is easier done with strings which do that automatically because they are immutable. There is no easy way to clone a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I only seem to get the following back : heavy duty, heavy cable, duty cable

Comment: Ignore that comment OK that's working thank you - is there a way to adapt so if 5 word string it would pick up the sub phrases of 3 words, and then step down and get the 2 word phrases as well